# How to get text from custom ListView using UiAutomator2+Appium?

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm getting the following structure from an Android app using Appium Inspector (with UiAutomator2):

```
(...)
<android.widget.Spinner index="1" package="something.something" class="android.widget.Spinner" text="[object Object]" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[64,1016][106,1060]" displayed="true">
  <android.widget.ListView index="0" package="something.something" class="android.widget.ListView" text="" resource-id="react-select-7--list" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1174][720,1384]" displayed="true">
    <android.view.View index="0" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-0" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="true" bounds="[0,1174][720,1280]" displayed="true" />
    <android.view.View index="1" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-1" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1278][720,1384]" displayed="true" />
    <android.view.View index="2" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-2" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1382][720,1384]" displayed="true" />
    <android.view.View index="3" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-3" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1382][720,1384]" displayed="true" />
    <android.view.View index="4" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-4" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1382][720,1384]" displayed="true" />
    <android.view.View index="5" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-5" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1382][720,1384]" displayed="true" />
    <android.view.View index="6" package="something.something" class="android.view.View" text="[object Object]" resource-id="react-select-7--option-6" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1382][720,1384]" displayed="true" />
  </android.widget.ListView>
</android.widget.Spinner>
(...)
```

This appears to be a custom implementation of list view, but I may be wrong about it.

The issue is that I'm able to see the text for every item of the list on screen but I can't get the text from it (I get `[object Object]` using `getText()`).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround for this?

Note that I have checked the entire XML content for occurrences of the text I'm looking for and it isn't present anywhere. I've also double checked that the items represented by the XML above are in fact the items in the list.

Comment: which library and language you are using to write your script ?

Comment: @AmitJain I'm using Java (jdk11) + JUnit 5 (5.4.0) + Selenium webdriver 3.141.59 + Appium 1.10.0 (with Java client v7.0.0).